# In Python, how do I apply astype(str) to the entire dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, mysql-python

So I got my api data pulled and sorted.  I'm looping thru my url like a breeze.  Have all the data going to .csv file then to mysql data using df.to_sql.  On a roll, then things changed.

goT this error during the push to db:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found
```

After researching/googling - i found tat the data type needs to be adjusted.
I want to set the datatype of the entire dataFrame to (str), but I can't figure out how to apply it to the code below that send everything to my db.

```
df.to_sql("contractList",engine, if_exists="replace", dtype=None, index=False)
```

How do I apply this df.astype(str) to the line of code above?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you means `dtype='str'` in `to_sql()` method? or `df.astype(str).to_sql()`

Comment: `df.to_sql("contractList",engine, if_exists="replace", dtype='str', index=False)` ?

Comment: Feel free to close the question if you already found a solution to it by researching.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal.  I am now getting this error: ValueError: The type of noticeId is not a SQLAlchemy type